# Python: Property setter using hasattr to provide validation and immutability

Tags: python, object, properties

I'm using a property to provide validation and self encapsulation for attributes of a class. The attribute should also be immutable. I'm currently have something like this:

```py
def __init__(self, the_attribute: str):
    self.the_attribute = the_attribute

@property
def the_attribute(self):
    return self._the_attribute

@the_attribute.setter
def the_attribute(self, value: str):
    if value is None:
        raise TypeError
    if hasattr(self, "_the_attribute"):
        raise AttributeError
    self._the_attribute = value
```

The `if hasattr(self, "_the_attribute")` checks whether the private attribute was previously set, and if so, raises an error. So when the object is initialized, the attribute is validated via the setter, and once set, is then immutable.

Are there any gotchas to be aware of in using `hasattr` in this way? My unit tests are passing so I believe it's logically correct, but it's not something I've used much in the past, so I want to ensure my logic is correct. Or perhaps there is a more elegant approach?

Comment: can the value of the `the_attribute` be an empty string?

Comment: Ideally the pattern I land on would work regardless of the attribute type or what it was set too. ie. it's been validated and set once, and so should now be immutable. I have this example, but I have other objects where the value could be an int, or some other type. In this example, if empty strings weren't allowed, then the setter would validate the value provided wasn't an empty string. Another approach I've considered is adding a class attribute: _the_attribute which is set to None. Instead of hasattr, I could then just use: if self._the_attribute is not None: raise AttributeError.